# Windows PowerShell can not find modules

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm very new to PowerShell and have not administered Windows in a while.  I have downloaded the Windows Update PowerShell module zip (http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) and put it in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WindowsUpdate`.  PowerShell is not finding these modules.

I don't want to store them in my User's directory. I want them to be in the same directories as all the other stock PS modules.

Comment: Watch this video. At 5:35, they tell you NOT to put your modules there. *THE* architect of Powershell is telling you - do not put your modules there.  Do not put your modules there.   http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/advpowershell3/09

(PS Don't put your modules there.)

Comment: @RyanRies Where should system-wide non-Microsoft modules live? Disclaimer: Started at 5:35, couldn't take much of the blad dude's jokes. Snover was doing a good job of humoring him though.

Answer (score 4):

Your question indicates you extracted to:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WindowsUpdate

This is not the correct directory. The module is named `PSWindowsUpdate`, and as such, should be in a directory named `PSWindowsUpdate`.  I extracted the zip to:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate

The following imports the module and works as expected:

`Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate`

Comment: (Old post, I know) Just a note you normally shouldn't be modifying that directory: That's what's shipped w/ Windows Powershell (older versions). Added, system-wide modules would by default go to %ProgramFiles%(PSVersionDependent)\Modules, so `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` (Versions up to 5) or `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules` (Ver 6 or higher) on default English installs.

Answer (score 2):

As in the video that I posted in the comment to your original question, you shouldn't put your modules in the same place where Microsoft puts their modules. (i.e., `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Modules`)

So where should you put your custom Powershell modules? The answer is simple.  You put your modules in one of the directories specified in your PSModulesPath environment variable, that *isn't* `System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Modules`.

```
PS C:\Users\ryan> $Env:PSModulePath -split ';'
C:\Users\ryan\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
```

Now I know that you only see a user-specific directory up there. But you can add whatever path you want to this environment variable. And you can do it machine-wide, so that it affects all users. You can do this in the GUI by going to Advanced System Properties, or you can do it on the command line using `setx`. The `set` command is only good for the current session, `setx` will set a persistent, system-wide variable.

You could also try putting the PS module in

`C:\Users\All Users\Documents\WindowsPowershell\Modules`

But I haven't tested that so you might still need to add an environment variable for that directory.

Edit: Lastly, don't forget to create a subdirectory your module, so if your module is named Foo, you need to create the subdirectory Foo under one of those PSModulePaths.

Enjoy your Powershell learning journey! :)

Comment: Sometimes I am looking so closely at a problem I don't see the *obvious* answer -- `%PSModulePath%`, `$env:PSModulePath` was right there all along. Thanks for clarifying what I should have already known. :)